# Products get displayed twice - once unformatted and a second time formatted - after db:seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I was studying a Rails 5 demo app, I was asked to modify the seeds.rb database creating some products directly there. Then I ran rails db:seed, and in the products#index where I created a view displaying in a loop the seeded products, I see now that products are shown twice:
once, in an unformatted way and below in the correct formatted layout. 
Here is the link to the screenshot and its repo

https://github.com/Adsidera/depot/issues/1

What is weird, I had the very same issue some days ago, on a totally different computer, developing a Rails/Bootstrapp app, with Rails 4, though. I had to modify the seeds.rb too, for creating a list of data (in this case fake customers), and everytime I display the related view (in this case "customers#index") I have exactly the same error
Do you have any clue?
thanks
Anna "Adsidera"

You can find the code in my git repo: this is the link to seeds.rb of the rails 5 app https://github.com/Adsidera/depot/blob/master/db/seeds.rb

Comment: please provide code samples and examples for the community to better understand your problem

Comment: Hello @sa77 , I have added the link to the git repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with seeds. The error is in your view. Somewhere you have something like this:

```
<%= @products.each do |product| %>
```

Don't need the `=` there. Should be

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
```

Comment: Thank you, Sergio Tulentsev! Indeed it was so simple...just a = that of course wasnt needed there :) !